# would changing dbml to bigint work for int values

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

our db is undergoing migration from int to bigint. In migrated partitions I have a column name in a table that is stored as bigint and in other partitions it is stored as int(to be migrated). Wondering if its possible to use a single datacontext to query both the databases. When i have the dbml as bigint and query in a db->table that has defined the column name as int. I get the below error

Specified cast is not valid.   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int64()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt64(Int32 i)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a workaround: Correctly declare all tables with their true datatype. Then convert them as part of the query. Example:

```
tableBigint.Select(x => x.ID)
tableInt.Select(x => (long)x.ID)
```

You would now be able to union them (or whatever you want to do with them) because the types match and also deserialization works.

Comment: sorry dint understand, could u please explain more. as only few partitions are being migrated, the table name remains same